# My body tag gets separated from ul element in Chrome

Tags: html

Is it not possible to put a ul element inside a body tag? For example:

```
<h1>Resume</h1>

        <div className="stuff">
                <hr/>
            <p className="head"><b>Education</b></p>
                    <body>
                    <p>Morehouse College, Bachelors of Science, Computer Science, May 2018</p>
                    <p>University of Chicago, PhD Machine Learning</p>
                    </body>
            <p className="head"><b>Technical Skills</b></p>
            <body>
            <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li className={"tech"}>Beginner proficiency with React and Angular frameworks</li>
                        <li className={"tech"}>Intermediate proficiency with Swift, Java, Python, C++, and Ruby on Rails</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            </body>
            <div className={"intern"}>
                <p><b>Internship Experience</b></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Recycling Club</li>
                        <li>Gardening Club</li>
                        <li>Book Club</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For some reason in the browser (Chrome) the body tag gets separated from the ul element and becomes a separate tag. Is there a reason this is happening?

Comment: I think there is a problem somewhere else.

Comment: `Why is it not possible to put a ul element inside a body tag?` it is possible.

Comment: @Jack what browser are you getting this issue?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: @Jack see my answer

Comment: Chrome's developer tools uses an HTML DOM parser that fixes some invalid HTML tags, allowing the page to still be rendered. Be sure you check the original code by right-clicking  and selecting "View page source" from the context menu. Then Look for invalid syntax in the original markup. The original source more than likely has an unclosed tag, which causes the DOM parser to place the `ul` element outside of the `body`

Comment: Yeah my original code is still the same and all my tags are closed but when I inspect the page the body is outside by itself for some reason @fyrye

Comment: Please paste your full source code into your question. As with just your code now I can't reproduce your issue in chrome. https://imgur.com/a/9wgRFIG

Comment: I just added the snippet

Comment: Your `body` element placement is invalid. It can only have a parent element of `<html>`. You would want to use an `article` element or something similar. https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20100304/body.html#body-context

Comment: I actually have an html tag, that was the only thing I forgot to copy. I don't want to waste anymore of your time, I will have to keep playing with it. Because for some reason the css for the body isn't being applied to the ul element

Comment: That's not what I am referencing. what it means is you can not have `<div><body>` it MUST only ever be `<html><body>` or `<html><head></head><body>`

Comment: Essential take out the div element?

Comment: @Jack No that will not be sufficient.  `body` must be a direct child of `html`, and the `html` element can only have two child elements: `body` and `head`.  You cannot have `body` as a sibling of the `p` element, as `p` cannot be a direct child of `html`.

Comment: As @Amy stated. No, you can only have one `body` element which must be an immediate child of the `html` element. Essentially replace your `body` elements in your question with `article` or something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Put it inside a `<div>` tag.

**Example:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>Home </li>
                <li> Link </li>
                <li> Link2 </li>
                <li> Link3 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

Previously i had answered the typical nature of chrome dev tools, visit here : [Inspect tool elements disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928807/inspect-tool-elements-disabled/53928860?r=SearchResults&s=2|17.8529#53928860)

Comment: So my body tag is correct but when I inspect the page, it does not cover my li elements and is separated for some reason. But my code in the actual inspector is correct. I'm not sure if you can make sense of that

Comment: @Jack see i answered this a while ago, similar problem a guy had with chrome dev tool as height property was not showing up correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928807/inspect-tool-elements-disabled/53928860?r=SearchResults&s=2|17.8529#53928860

Comment: You were downvoted since you don't need to wrap the `ul` element inside a div element. It is valid to have it as a child of the body https://imgur.com/a/9wgRFIG. In addition it does not address why the `ul` element would be placed under the body element in chrome dev tools, as the OP did not include enough information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @fyrye this i know perfectly, i was trying to show it to OP, as in initial he asked the other way, so i gave him that solution. BTW you also commented that "it is possible", don't you think op at that time meant if it is possible?

Comment: I typically do and did.. I was addressing the issues with your answer while writing the comment. As well as responding to the OP's comments. As for the revisions to the question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54135821/revisions When you answered it was `Is it possible to put a ul tag inside a My body tag`  or `My body tag? gets separated from ul element in Chrome`  with the OP's code and the result. To which your answer does not address. Your answer says, `Yes it is possible. Put it inside a <div> tag.`, which is not correct.